# remove - using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
import regex as re
def tokenize(text):
    return re.findall(r'[\w-][-]*\p{L}[\w-]*',text)
text ="let's defeat the SARS-coV-2 delta variant together in 2021!"
tokens= tokenize(text)
print("|".join(tokens))
```

My output is like that

**let|defeat|the|SARS-coV-2|delta|variant|together|in**

I would like to get the following out put with no -
**|Let|s|defeat|the|SARS|CoV|Delta|variant|together|in**

Comment: `|Let|s|...`? Even it's just a single letter? Why not `|Let's|...`?

Comment: What's the pattern? It doesn't seem to follow any pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your regex pattern by just using [re.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) on the characters that you consider as word-separators such as apostrophe `'`, space  , dash `-`, etc.

```
from itertools import filterfalse
import regex as re

def tokenize(text):
    splits = re.split("['\s\-]", text)
    splits = list(filterfalse(lambda value: re.search("\d", value), splits))  # Remove this line if you wish to include the digits
    if splits:
        splits[0] = splits[0].capitalize()
    return splits

text ="let's defeat the SARS-coV-2 delta variant together in 2021!"
tokens= tokenize(text)
print("|" + "|".join(tokens))  # Remove <"|" +> if you don't intend to put a "|" at the start.
```

Output:

```
|Let|s|defeat|the|SARS|coV|delta|variant|together|in
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use re.sub to replace series of non-letters by the pipe delimiter:

```
import re

def tokenize(text):
    return re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z]+", "|", text)

text ="let's defeat the SARS-coV-2 delta variant together in 2021!"
print(tokenize(text))
let|s|defeat|the|SARS|coV|delta|variant|together|in|
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to extract any sequence of word chars if this "word" contains at least one letter.

You can achieve this with `regex` (where `\p{L}` can be used to match any letter) and `re` modules (where `[^\W\d_]` matches any letter):

```py
# Python PyPi regex:
import regex as re
def tokenize(text):
    return re.findall(r'\w*\p{L}\w*',text)

# Python built-in re:
import re
def tokenize(text):
    return re.findall(r'\w*[^\W\d_]\w*',text)
```

[Python PyPi `regex` demo](https://tio.run/##VY65DsJADET7/QoTiiQIEIQOCSR6KpCoaFZgyELwRhtzm28P5ipwM9Z4PHrllXNPg7p2h9IHhoBbvICtdDGMF4ZRVCDHFaxxg5aBc4T5ZDbvrPyik6lbsIWTDc6SHv0WNRDAEWS9rN@IjNE/9fdI7obJqzEdGtAJyMdAKt2No7UtiiTEy3NrWd6nD9W4/c4aUwZHnEQSdXfeUfJflaamCaMxKKJU8kEUJZAXoiiivAHlCyg/QHFU108):

```
import regex as re
text ="let's defeat the SARS-coV-2 delta variant together in 2021!"

def tokenize(text):
    return re.findall(r'\w*\p{L}\w*',text)

print("|".join(tokenize(text)))
# => let|s|defeat|the|SARS|coV|delta|variant|together|in
```

[Python `re` demo](https://ideone.com/6IJRmI):

```
import re
text ="let's defeat the SARS-coV-2 delta variant together in 2021!"
def tokenize(text):
    return re.findall(r'\w*[^\W\d_]\w*',text)

print("|".join(tokenize(text)))
# => let|s|defeat|the|SARS|coV|delta|variant|together|in
```